# Excel VBA - Apply formulas dynamically causing error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a requirement where I need to write a formula dynamically using VBA.

I am able to find the Column Name and Row Number. Now how do I apply it in a formula ?

```
Colm = WorksheetFunction.Match("Name", Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(5), 0)
BuName = GetColumnName(Colm)
Row = WorksheetFunction.Match("Name", Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(Colm), 0)
```

The `BuName` returns a String which is "A". The `Row` Returns the number which is 2.

Now I tried to Apply it in a formula using VBA like this,

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AQ1").Formula = "=$'BuName'$Row&$A$10"
```

Does anyone Know how to write the formula for that?

Comment: `"=$" & BuName & "$ & Row & ":$A$10"`, not that that formula makes any sense.

Comment: @SJR It still throws an error. Saying expected end of statement

Comment: "=$" & BuName & "$" & Row & ":$A$10 -This works. Thanks

Comment: As I say your formula doesn't make sense - it equates to '=$A$2:$A$10'. What are you trying to achieve? Edit - apologies, I missed a quote.

Comment: Thanks. I am just trying to combine both the columns and produce it in AQ1. I tried to keep an & in the place of : in your formula. Still it produces an error..

Comment: You need to explain what is your desired end result in this case.

Comment: I want the result to be =A2&A10.

Comment: "=$" & BuName & "$" & Row & "&$A$10"

Comment: Yes tried that. It says object doesn't support this property or this method

Comment: Works for me `Range("aq1").Formula = "=$" & BuName & "$" & Row & "&$A$10"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Dim Colm, Row As Long
Dim BuName As String

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Colm = WorksheetFunction.Match("Name", .Rows(5), 0)
    BuName = GetColumnName(Colm)
    Row = WorksheetFunction.Match("Name", .Columns(Colm), 0)

    .Range("AQ1").Formula = "=$" & BuName & "$" & Row & "&$A$10"
End With
```